# Symfony4 Error loading classes custom folder "Expected to find class... but it was not found"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

### Problem

I'm trying to setup a custom directory structure 
for some shared classes in my Symfony project. I
want to create a custom folder in the root of my
project and I want to use the Symfony auto-load 
feature to automatically register services from 
that folder.

So I added a custom services namespace to the
services.yaml file:

```
# src ./config/services.yaml
services:
    ...

    TestNamespace\:
    resource: '../TestNamespace/*'

  ...
```

And I added an empty class in the custom folder:

```
# src ./TestNamespace/TestClass.php

namespace TestNamespace;

class TestClass
{

}
```

When I run the app I get the following error:

```
(1/2) InvalidArgumentException
Expected to find class "TestNamespace\TestClass" in file 
"/path/to/ClassLoadErrorDemo/demo/TestNamespace/TestClass.php"
while importing services from resource 
"../TestNamespace/*", but it was not found! Check the
namespace prefix used with the resource.

(2/2) FileLoaderLoadException
Expected to find class "TestNamespace\TestClass" in file 
"/path/to/ClassLoadErrorDemo/demo/TestNamespace/TestClass.php" while 
importing services from resource "../TestNamespace/*", but it was not 
found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in 
/path/to/ClassLoadErrorDemo/demo/config/services.yaml (which is loaded 
in resource "/path/to/ClassLoadErrorDemo/demo/config/services.yaml").
```

I double checked the paths, namespace and the class 
name multiple times and everything seems fine and I 
don't understand why I still get the error.
Controllers in the ./src folder seem to load fine.
What am I doing wrong here?

### Steps to reproduce

I created a demo repo to isolate the problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/smoelker/SymfonyClassLoadErrorDemo.git
cd SymfonyClassLoadErrorDemo/demo
composer install
mv TestNamespace/TestClass.php_ TestNamespace/TestClass.php
php bin/console server:start
```

Comment: Is `TestClass` inside the `src` directory?

Comment: No, it's not inside the source directory and that's exactly what I want to accomplish here. I want to put these classes outside of the src folder.

Comment: Need to adjust the psr4 section of composer.json and then run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Update your composer.json autoload setup

```
{
    [...]
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TestNamespace\\": "TestNamespace/",
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    [...]
}
```

After run: `composer dump-autoload` and try again.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` did the trick for me. Apparently `bin/console  server:run` does not trigger it, and it has to be executed manually.

Comment: The problem for me was not executing the `composer dump-autoload` command. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to go crazy. +1

Comment: I'm trying to add another namespaced file inside the src/ directory but it is failing with the same message. I have autoload set up properly in my composer.json class os it was working, but this was before I installed symfony. So it seems to have something to do with the way symfony registers classes.

Answer (score 3):

`composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative` will only work if your `src` directory is present at the time you run the command.

This can be an issue with multi-stage Docker builds in particular, when you are normally only copying the `composer.json`/`composer.lock` into the build image.