# Symfony 4: Create a custum Service Error: Expected to find class

Tags: symfony4

I've a problem with  creation of a custom sumfony 4 service: I've created a custom class UtilasteurService in sub-folder src/CustumService. But when i run the command  `php bin/console debug:autowiring` I've the following error.

> Expected to find class "App\CustumService\UtilisateurService" in file
>   "C:\wamp\www\semges_api\src/CustumService\UtilisateurService.php"
>   while im   porting services from resource "../src/*", but it was not
>   found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

See below my service.yml file and UtilisateurService file.

**#service.yml**

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
services:
      _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

***#src/CustumService\UtilisateurService.php***

```
namespace App\CustumService;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UtilisateurService
{
    private $passwd;

    public function __construct($motdepasse)
    {
      $this->paswd=$motdepasse;
    }

    public function encodePassword($motdepasse )
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($motdepasse);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony4 Error loading classes custom folder "Expected to find class... but it was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954510/symfony4-error-loading-classes-custom-folder-expected-to-find-class-but-it-w)

Answer (score 3):

Greattttttttt thank you to all. I've solved my problem by executig this command: `composer dump-autoload`

I get this solution by reading the solution of this problem : [Symfony4 Error loading classes custom folder "Expected to find class... but it was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954510/symfony4-error-loading-classes-custom-folder-expected-to-find-class-but-it-w?rq=1)

## Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your setup. Maybe try to clear the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear` and then try again?

Works for me:

```
Autowirable Services
====================

 The following classes & interfaces can be used as type-hints when autowiring:

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  App\Controller\IndexController
  App\CustumService\UtilisateurService
```

Comment: Thank you @symques.  Even when i want to execute the clear command,php bin/console cache:clear 
 i've the same error